# User profile unable to access file server

Tags: active-directory, file-sharing

I have a user whos is unable to access the file server from his workstation, his user account can access it from other machines, I'm able to access it using my account on his computer.

I'm assuming its a corrupted local profile? Normally I would just remove and recreate the profile, but.. He's a developer with extensive settings stored into his programs, and it would take at least a day possibly two in order to recreate everything.

What I can I do short of rebuilding his profile?

Comment: What happens when he tries to access the file server? How is he trying to access the file server?

Comment: IP, FQDN, UNC. He gets access denied. As if he doesnt have permissions. But only from that profile, on that workstation.

Comment: Take a look at any cached credentials on the workstation (Stored User Names and Passwords or Credential Manager, depending on the client OS). He may have credentials cached for that resource that don't have the required permissions.

Comment: thanks joe, that was it, I needed a different perspective. Diddnt even think of cached credentials.

Comment: Glad to help. I'll post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at any cached credentials on the workstation (Stored User Names and Passwords or Credential Manager, depending on the client OS). He may have credentials cached for that resource that don't have the required permissions.